# How to use current Workflow state as a Panels selection rule

Tags: 7, panels, workflows, chaos-tool-suite

How can I use a nodes current [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow/) state as a selection rule in the Panels Page Manager UI?

It does not seem to be available under "Selection rules."

Comment: Did you find a way? I guess there are two options: a PHP code selection rule, or a custom ctools plugin that provides a selection rule.

Comment: Added an answer regarding how I worked around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new select list field that would update to match the current workflow state each time the workflow changed.  I was able to use this field in panels and could accomplish what I needed.

It's not perfect, but it works.